# How to configure pip so that pip install is always called with argument --user?

Tags: python, pip, persistence, jupyter-lab

I'm configuring a jupyterlab single-user instance. The users will need to install Python packages using

```
pip install <package-name>
```

I want to configure pip so that `pip install` is always called with argument `--user`, even if it is invoked without `--user`. Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

The reason behind it is that the $HOME directory is mounted on a persistent volume, and I want the user to still have its packages installed after restarting the jupyterlab server. By installing packages using `pip install --user <package-name>`, the packages will be stored in `$HOME/.local/lib/python${PY_MAJOR}.${PY_MINOR}/site-packages` and will therefore persist even after a server restart.

Comment: A solution would be to configure an additional persistent volume to the location of the python packages. I'm afraid it would slow down any usage of Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that works on ubuntu:

Add this in `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[install]
user = yes
```

***Documentation***:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-user

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install <package-name>
```

#To run this code command prompt on python terminal to install a package

```
pip install --user
```

#python packages name on terminal to install  with the help of
pycharm